# divide time 0900 to 09:00

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, divide

If I enter 0900 in this text field then I would like it to automatically turn into 09:00

**form**

```
<form action="form.html">
  <p>
    <label>time:</label>
    <input type="text" name="time" class="time"/>
  </p>
  <span id="error" class="hide">Error in the field</span>
</form>
```

I Know I should use the following to at least get the value and then I have to turn that value into the value that I want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".time").on("focusout",function(){
    var old_value = $(this).val();

    // The old value to the new value
    if(old_value.length < 2 || > 4){
      $("#error").show();
    } else {
      if(old_value.length == 2){
        // Then add 2 leading zero's
        // Then add a : in the middle
      } else if (old_value.length == 3){
        // Then add 1 leading zero's
        // Then add a : in the middle
      } else if (old_value.length == 4){
        // Then add a : in the middle
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance for the effort taken. If something isn't clear please ask me.

Comment: show your code, html, something you have tried till now.

Comment: I've changed the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this as a basis to solve your problem:

```
$("#your_filed_id").on("focusout", function(){
    // Do whatever checking you like here 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ha9kx/1/

**HTML:**

```
<form action="demo_form.html">
    <p>
        <label>Hour:</label>
        <input type="text" name="hour" class="hour_modification"/>
    </p>
    <span id="error" class="hide">Error in the field</span>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hour_modification").on("focusout",function(){
        var old_val = $(this).val();
        if (old_val.length > 4 || old_val.length < 3){
            $("#error").show();
        }
        else{
            if(old_val.length = 3){old_val = "0" + old_val;}
            var new_val = old_val.substring(0,old_val.length-2) + ":" + old_val.substring(old_val.length-2);
            $(this).val(new_val);
        }
    });
});
```

This solution will work even if the user put "300" for "03:00"

Answer (score 0):

If the entered value is always going to be 4 characters in the format you specified above, the following code should work. I don't use jQuery that often, but the following should give you an idea of what is required. You can modify the event listener with jQuery along with the selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/DS92Z/

```
<input type="text" id="time" />
<script>
   var input = document.getElementById('time');
   input.addEventListener('blur',function(e) {
      var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
      var value = target.value;
      if(value.length != 4) {
         return false;
      }
      target.value = value[0]+value[1]+':'+value[2]+value[3];
   },false);
</script>
```